# Проверка номера телефона через регулярные выражения

Tags: python

У меня есть строка, в которой хранится номер телефона. Мне надо проверить, соответствует ли данная строка регулярному выражению

```regex
^((\+?7|8)[ \-] ?)?((\(\d{3}\))|(\d{3}))?([ \-])?(\d{3}[\- ]?\d{2}[\- ]?\d{2})$
```

Comment: Телефонный номер может состоять из любого количества цифр. `\d+` вот и вся проверка. Зачем его вообще проверять? Вы что звонить собрались? А если по формату введёт чужой номер? Что толку от вашей проверки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> У меня есть строка, в которой хранится номер телефона. Мне надо проверить, соответствует ли данная строка регулярному выражению

я немного прокачал ваше регулярное выражение, суть вы поймёте

```
import re
number = '74957556983'
result = re.match(r'^(\+7|7|8)?[\s\-]?\(?[489][0-9]{2}\)?[\s\-]?[0-9]{3}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}$', number)
print(bool(result))  # True, False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.match(r'^((\+?7|8)[ \-] ?)?((\(\d{3}\))|(\d{3}))?([ \-])?(\d{3}[\- ]?\d{2}[\- ]?\d{2})$', number)
```

Comment: Не работает. Если ввести 8916202, то он принимает это за полный номер

Comment: @Илья так вы определитесь, проверка на соответствие регулярке или на номер телефона.